# Javafx: TextField Handler

Tags: java, javafx, nodes, fxml

I don't know why but class member `newContact` is not getting any data and when I try to print it, it prints null.

Here is the code :

```java
public class CreatContact_Controller {
    @FXML
    private VBox vBox;

    private Contact contact;
    private ArrayList<String> newContact = null;
    private ArrayList<TextField> textFields = null;

    void initData(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact.clon();
        editFields();
    }

    private void editFields(){

        for(int loop = 0 ; loop < contact.getPlaceHolders().size() ; loop++){
            HBox hBox = new HBox();
            Label label = new Label("Add the new " + contact.getPlaceHolders().get(loop));
            TextField textField = new TextField();
            textField.setOnAction(getTextField);
            hBox.getChildren().addAll(label, textField);
            vBox.getChildren().add(hBox);
        }
    }

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> getTextField =
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    newContact.add(((TextField)event.getSource()).getText());
                    System.out.println(((TextField)event.getSource()).getText());
                }
            };
}
```

How to fix so it adds the value of the textfield ?

Comment: According to the code you posted, an element is added to `newContact` when the user presses the ENTER key in one of the `TextField`s.

Comment: Is there any way to add a new element without pressing enter?

Comment: Not according to the code you posted. You should [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve, because it is not clear to me from your question. What is your application supposed to do?

Comment: There's no assignment to the `newContact` field in the code other than the initialisation with `null`. Why do you expect this to change?